# Alignment problems with <iomanip>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, text-alignment, iomanip

So I'm using the `iomanip` library to cout this:

```
std::cout << std::endl
    << std::left << std::setw(15) << "Ticker Symbol"
    << std::setw(100) << "Stock Name"
    << std::setw(12) << "Value"
    << std::setw(10) << "Date"
    << std::setw(10) << "YTD Return"
    << std::endl;
```

The problem is that it ends up printing this:

```
T       icker SymbolS                       tock NameV      alueD       ateY    TD Return
```

Instead of:

```
Ticker Symbol    Stock Name                            Value    Date    YTD Return
```

Is there a way I can fix this without using another library?

Edit: My Operator overloading function appears to be causing this issue:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const char array[])
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        out << array[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

That being said, I still don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: A shot in the dark: does flushing the stream in between writes help?

Comment: Putting `std::cout.flush();` before that code doesn't do anything.

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f71dfe3af6aa51f)

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my system. What compiler are you using? Can you provide a minimal, reproducible test case?

Comment: This looks like a bug in your compiler's standard library. Which platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7.

Comment: Just checked (MSVC, Windows 7) - works OK.

Comment: @SergeyA If I create a new project I can't reproduce this error, even if I use the same header and cpp files. I think I'm just going to delete this question.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest VS2013 (update 5 I think). I cannot reproduce this in VS2013 on Win10, even if I imbue cout with a left-to-right locale like Hebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have to overload the operator?  That is certainly what is causing your problem.

`setw` will get applied to the first thing output to the stream, and because you have c-strings output one letter at a time, the `setw` gets applied to only the first letter - producing the behavior you are seeing.

The easiest thing to do is get rid of your operator overload.  Otherwise you need to get the width from `cout.width()`, output one letter at a time, then add in the extra spaces afterward:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const char array[])
{
    int width = out.width();
    out.width(0);
    int array_size = 0;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++, array_size++)
    {
        out << array[i];
    }

    for (int i = array_size; i < width; i++)
    {
        out << " ";
    }

    return out;
}
```